# How can I get all keys in System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, dictionary, key

How can I get all keys in System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary without using foreach?

I have a method

```
void Get(IDictionary options)
{
...
}
```

And while debugging I can set up a breakpoints inside a body of this method. I want to see all keys of `options` in the watch window in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: That class was a .NET 1.x hack to work around perf problems with Hashtable.  You should *not* be using that class anymore, the generic Dictionary<> class doesn't have these problems.  Which has a Keys property.

Comment: Erm, so where does HybridDictionary come into play?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, it was a bad example. In the Get() method I have received an object of type System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary and I can't change this external code. Please, focus on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.hybriddictionary.keys.aspx), are you looking for that?

```
var allKeys = dict.Keys;
```

MSDN

> Gets an `ICollection` containing the keys in the `HybridDictionary`.
>
> The order of the values in the ICollection is unspecified, but it is
>   the same order as the associated values in the ICollection returned by
>   the Values method.
>
> Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation.

If you instead want to access it like a `List`(what is not necessarily a good idea as you can see from the remark section of msdn quoted above):

```
var allKeys = new List<object>(dict.Keys.Count);
allKeys.AddRange(dict.Keys.Cast<object>());
```

(which uses a loop implicitely anyway)

**Edit**:

> Actually I need to see all keys in the watch window while debugging in
>   Visual Studio 2010. I can't use foreach and List in the watch window.

Then execute this in the quick-watch-window:

```
string.Join("," , dict.Keys.Cast<object>());
```

Comment: @Warlock: Edited my answer. Replace `","` with `Environment.NewLine` if you want to split the items by line instead of comma.

Comment: @Warlock: Are you using .NET >= 3.5? Add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: @Warlock: I'm also using VS 2010(.NET 4.0) and it works without a problem in the quick-watch window. [**Here's**](http://www.bilder-hochladen.net/files/k9jr-1-c4ca.jpg) a screenshot.

Comment: @Warlock: So have you added `using System.Linq;` as i've asked above? Does it work  outside of the debugger?

Comment: @Warlock: As i've mentioned above - 2010 and it's compiled as debug. You might want to ask another question since it seems to be indeed a Visual Studio setting question and this issue is not related to your original question anymore.